# Rails3, cucumber problem

Tags: rubygems, cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to follow [this](http://blog.adsdevshop.com/2010/06/06/tdd-on-the-bleeding-edge-with-ruby193-rails3-rspec-cucumber-autotest-and-factory-girl/) tutorial. Autotest fails with this error message:

> sg $autotest
>   loading autotest/cucumber_rails_rspec2
>   Error loading Autotest style autotest/cucumber_rails_rspec2 (no such file to load --   autotest/rails_rspec2). Aborting.

Gem list:

> abstract (1.0.0)
>   actionmailer (3.0.0.beta4)
>   actionpack (3.0.0.beta4)
>   activemodel (3.0.0.beta4)
>   activerecord (3.0.0.beta4)
>   activeresource (3.0.0.beta4)
>   activesupport (3.0.0.beta4)
>   arel (0.4.0)
>   autotest (4.3.2)
>   autotest-rails (4.1.0)
>   builder (2.1.2)
>   bundler (1.0.0.beta.5)
>   configuration (1.1.0)
>   cucumber (0.8.5)
>   cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
>   culerity (0.2.10)
>   diff-lcs (1.1.2)
>   erubis (2.6.6)
>   ffi (0.6.3)
>   gherkin (2.1.4)
>   i18n (0.4.1)
>   json_pure (1.4.3)
>   launchy (0.3.5)
>   mail (2.2.5)
>   mime-types (1.16)
>   nokogiri (1.4.2)
>   polyglot (0.3.1)
>   rack (1.1.0)
>   rack-mount (0.6.9)
>   rack-test (0.5.4)
>   rails (3.0.0.beta4)
>   railties (3.0.0.beta4)
>   rake (0.8.7)
>   rdoc (2.5.9, 2.5.8)
>   rspec (2.0.0.beta.17)
>   rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.17)
>   rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.17)
>   rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.17)
>   selenium-webdriver (0.0.24)
>   sqlite3-ruby (1.3.1)
>   sys-uname (0.8.4)
>   term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
>   test-spec (0.10.0)
>   test-unit (2.1.0)
>   thor (0.13.8)
>   treetop (1.4.8)
>   trollop (1.16.2)
>   tzinfo (0.3.22)
>   webrat (0.7.1)
>   ZenTest (4.3.3)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bundle exec](http://exviva.posterous.com/running-autotest-with-rails-3) helped.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (rails3, ruby1.9.2)

## features/support/env.rb

require 'webrat'
require 'webrat/core/matchers'

Webrat.configure do |config|
  config.mode = :rails
  config.open_error_files = false # Set to true if you want error pages to pop up in the browser
end

## make a feature

## bash prompt

AUTOFEATURE=true autotest -rails

## Gemfile

source 'http://rubygems.org'
source :gemcutter

gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

## Bundle edge Rails instead:

## gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'sinatra'

group :development do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'cucumber'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'    # So you can do Then show me the page
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  #gem 'spork' 
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'ZenTest'
end

...hope that helps!